# Create variable at runtime

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android application and I need to create some variables at runtime.

I try this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String var+i = "number is: " + i;
}
```

I thought I can set name of variable like this (var+i) but this is not allow because arithmetic symbols are not allow in variable name.

Is there any way to do this, I want to create some variables at runtime.

Comment: i think if we knew what you are doing with those created variables we might be able to help you better. There may be better options rather than trying to create variables.

Comment: I have that slight feeling, that it's arrays, you're looking for. Also a basic java tutorial is very recommendable.

Comment: actually i have 10 String variable with different values. So I think that if I create a single variable and rename it at runtime and also change its value and store it to an ArrayList for future use.

if anyhow is it possible then please tell me how?

Comment: @cypressious if any tutorial solve my problem then please provide some tutorial for that, but keep in mind i want to create some variable at RUNTIME.

Comment: I want to have a Range Rover with M800 steering at RUNTIME, is there any way to do this? Would you ask this, no? Ask something which does mean something!

Comment: You know what, you're lucky I'm not going to be the fourth guy to vote you down!

Comment: I see what you're trying to do and it's _not possible in Java_. Look at the answers. Use either a `String[]` or a `Collection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a variable name like that at all. If you only care about being able to generate a bunch of variables and don't care what the name actually is, then consider an array large enough for the most you think you'll want, or a Vector if you just don't know how many.

Comment: Actually I am new on android and I don't know about Vector.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
String[] strings = null;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
strings[i] = "Number is " + i;
```

You can also use ArrayList

Comment: you are storing a string at i index. if i do this then how can i change my variable name, can i do somthing like Sting strings[1];?

Comment: I think you need to explain to us *why* you want to change the name of a variable? What do you believe this is going to achieve? A value either has to go into a variable with a hard-coded name, or it goes into a container that has a hard-coded name (but the elements of that container have no name). I believe you simply want to be able to store many different strings [in a loop] without giving every single one of them a hard-coded name... that is what [fixed] arrays, ArrayLists or Vectors are for - storing many items of one type but each with its own value.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative may be using String[] array. You are not clear on how you want to use those variables, but you can achieve almost same functionality using arrays.

For example, `var1 = number is 1`,

instead you need to do

```
array[1] = number is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible. However you can go for arrays..

```
String var[] = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    var[i] = "number is: " + i;
                    var[i] = new String();
                }
```

Comment: I want to change variable name at runtime, and in this way I only store a String value into an Array.